# USB Loader GX problem with Wii games

Tags: technical-issues, mods, nintendo-wii, homebrew

I used to have no problems with my USB loader GX before (i can play any games that i have downloaded from the internet) but when i try playing my existing games that i have bought in discs before, my wii disc mounter would first take it in then spit it out halfway then take it in again and completely spits it out that my disc would fall. i think there's probably(?) a problem with the disc mounter after i installed usb loader GX and the D2x-CIos installer.

I tried downloading those same games that i used to have in discs from the internet, i did verify them and there's nothing wrong with it, but whenever i try to play it on my usb loader gx, it would take me back to the Homebrew menu.

Ex. I have the Harry Potter Order of the Phoenix disc game, since my wii won't accept the disc, I have to download that same game from the internet with verification there's nothing wrong with it. But the downloaded game returns me back to the Homebrew menu. I did delete the saved game from my wii's system but the situation didn't change.

Sounds complicated but I really hope there's an answer to what I asked for. Please do help me out. I already did searched Google for similar situations to mine and this now is my only hope 
:(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and managed to fix it by transfering the .WBFS or .ISO files from Wii Backup Manager. Transferring the game to the drive appears to make it run properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the usbloader gx not being able to recognize my games after a few months of it working.

Some things that helped me.

- run usbloader-gx from the sd card
- reinstall all the cios versions like the guides online suggest (using d2x-cios)
- re-downloading it and reinstalling usbloader-gx into the apps folder

I don't know which of those things is what made the difference but they were the steps that worked. I think reinstalling the cios versions and reinstalling usbloader-gx made the biggest difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the USB ports from the hard drive.

Comment: Can you add more information? This is vague and of low quality.